# I want to join five tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

### Books

- bookid (PK)
- title
- price

### author

- authored (PK)
- authorname

### publisher

- pubid (PK)
- pubname

### bookauthors

- bookid (FK)
- authorid

### bookpublisher

- bookid (FK)
- pubid

I want to join all five tables and get these column values:

- bookid
- title
- price
- authorname
- pubname

I should get only one row for a query to get above result. What I wrote was:

```
select books.*, authors.authorname
from authors,books
inner join bookauthors on books.bookid = bookauthors.bookid
inner join publisherbook on books.bookid = publisherbook.bookid
where books.bookid = 459567;
```

but instead I am getting many rows with duplicate data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use joins for **all** the tables. Using multiple tables in the `FROM` clause results in a Cartesian product. Try this

```
SELECT books.bookid, books.title, books.price, authors.authorname
FROM books
INNER JOIN bookauthors ON books.bookid = bookauthors.bookid
INNER JOIN publisherbook ON books.bookid = publisherbook.bookid
INNER JOIN authors ON bookauthors.authorid = authors.authorid -- assuming you meant authorid and not authored
WHERE books.bookid = 459567;
```

Of course, if your book has multiple authors, you **will** get multiple rows in your resultset.

I'm not sure why you're joining in `publisherbook` (or `bookpublisher` from your original list) unless you're just ensuring that your book has a publisher. Again, multiple publishers will result in even more (duplicate) results.

If you just want to make sure your book has at least one publisher, try this instead...

```
SELECT books.bookid, books.title, books.price, authors.authorname
FROM books
INNER JOIN bookauthors ON books.bookid = bookauthors.bookid
INNER JOIN authors ON bookauthors.authorid = authors.authorid -- assuming you meant authorid and not authored
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM publisherbook
    WHERE publisherbook.bookid = books.bookid
) AND books.bookid = 459567;
```